# Android Studio native library build - NDK clang permission problem on Mac

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio-4.0

Trying to build a native C library in Android Studio 4.0 on a Mac.  But getting this pop-up when I do:

```
"clang" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.  macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.
```

Of note: I downloaded NDK r21 and point to it in Android Studio.  Also, in the Android SDK setup, I have NDK (side-by-side) installed. I have to admit I am not clear what NDK is pointed to when one checks NDK (side-by-side)?  That is why I downloaded NDK r21 and pointed to it in Android Studio.  But now, this NDK clang permission problem...

thanks for any advice.

Best,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

OK - I went to, in Android Studio, File -> Project Structure, and removed the PATH I had for the Android NDK Location box.  And kept the NDK (side-by-side) box checked in the SDK Manager, SDK Tools tab section.  Now not seeing the clang issue.